# Is there a steering wheel that works with L.A. Noire on the Xbox 360?

Tags: xbox-360, la-noire

L.A. Noire is a great game, but if you're not used to driving with a controller, it's hard to play some parts of it. It seems to me it would be much easier with a steering wheel. Anybody know if there's one that works with it on the Xbox 360?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm going to go out on a bit of a limb and say no, there isn't any wheel that works in L.A. Noire.

[This site](http://www.steering-wheel-support.com/PS3/LA-Noire-PS3.php) says no PS3 wheels are supported, and I see no reason why it'd be different on the Xbox 360. If nothing else, the steering wheels are full-blown controllers so you wouldn't be able to easily swap one in and out just for the driving sequences.

Comment: That's what I'd also guessed based on results from search engines, but I was hoping someone might know something different.

Comment: In L.A. Noire you can also, of course, just instruct your partner to drive if you're finding that aspect of the game difficult/boring/whatever.